# DVI-D single link not working in DVI to VGA adapter for monitor

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, vga, dvi

I have this GPU: [ASUS GTX 1080](https://www.asus.com/Graphics-Cards/TURBO-GTX1080-8G/)

And this converter: [Goobay MMK ADAP DVI F > 15 pin HD M (VGA) DVI-I 15 VGA HD M](https://www.bol.com/nl/p/goobay-mmk-adap-dvi-f-15-pin-hd-m-dvi-i-15-vga-hd-m/9200000024126514/?s2a=#product_specifications)

And this monitor: [Samsung S22D300NY](https://www.samsung.com/latin_en/business/business-monitors/led-ls22d300ny/)

The question is, I am using a DVI-D single link to DVI-D single link. The Adapter is connecting into the monitor and the cable goes from my GPU to the adapter which goes into the monitor. It does display on windows and the monitor does register as working since it does not give the signal that says that nothing is connected. The screen is black.

What would the solution be? Can I buy a HDMI to VGA adapter instead? (The port is [RGB-IN])

Comment: Neither the GPU nor the monitor have a VGA port according to the pages you linked to, so it doesn't look like trying to use a VGA adapter will help. See the user manual for the monitor for your options.

Answer (score 0):

Your adaptor is passive.

You need an active adaptor to go from DVI-D to VGA. A passive adaptor can only go from DVI-A [or I], as it simply uses the analogue transmission.

[This](https://www.amazon.co.uk/StarTech-com-DVI-D-Active-Adapter-Converter/dp/B00C93JQXS) or anything like it - search "dvi-d to vga"

Comment: Will this work? https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B079997Y8P?ref=ppx_pt2_dt_b_prod_image

Comment: Looks like it will, yes.